# write a REPL: where to start?

Tags: compiler-construction, interpreter, haxe, read-eval-print-loop

I learned Ruby and Scala, and they both have a great REPLs. The interactive tools help me a lot when learning a language.

Recently I'm learning Haxe and found it doesn't have a real REPL(just a crippled shell language).

My ultimate goal is to make a REPL for Haxe. But I know it takes a lot of work that can't be accomplished with my current knowledge. So where should I start? Are there good tutorials/books about REPL? Or a REPL for a toy language for education whose source code I can read?

Comment: Do you really have to write your own REPL shell? Why not reusing a generic one, like `rlwrap`?

Comment: Yes in fact I planned to start from `rlwrap`. But read/print/loop are all simple parts. The problem is how to eval code of a compiled language interactively on its runtime. In Haxe case, I mean Neko VM.

Answer (score 2):

There is a [REPL for Haxe](https://github.com/ianxm/ihx):

```
haxelib install ihx
```

Also [this old thread](http://old.haxe.org/forum/thread/3395#nabble-td6622983) may be of interest.

They mention [`hscript`](https://github.com/HaxeFoundation/hscript). Presumably that is the "crippled shell language" you are talking about.

They also mention two tips for scripting:

```
haxe --macro MyClass.myMethod()
```

and:

```
haxe -x MyClass
(call MyClass.main())
```